# How to plot the binomial function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
def fac(n):
    value = 1
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        value = value * i
    return value

def C(n,k):
    return fac(n)/(fac(k) * (fac(n-k)))

for k in range(1,100):
    for n in [10,20,30]:
        F=C(n,k)
plt.plot(k,F)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I wanna plot the binomial function as a function in `k` for certain `n` values say for `n = 10, 20, 30, ...`

However, I do not know how to plot that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect, there's a specific reason not to use [NumPy](https://numpy.org), so here's a solution using plain Python.

If you're talking about [binomial **distribution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), then the formula needs to incorporate the probability *p*. I added that in the code below. (If you actually only want to have the [binomical coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), delete the two `pow` terms.)

In general, for plotting, you need to collect your *x* and *y* values in some arrays (say `X` and `Y`), so that you can use `plt.plot(X, Y)` to plot the whole function.

In your example, you also need to switch the two loops, because you want to have three functions, each for `k = [1 ... 100]`.

That'd be my solution:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def fac(n):
    value = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        value = value * i
    return value

def C(n, k, p):
    return fac(n)/(fac(k) * (fac(n-k))) * pow(p, k) * pow(1-p, n-k)

for N in [10, 20, 30]:
    X = []
    Y = []
    for K in range(1, 100):
        X.append(K)
        Y.append(C(N, K, 0.5))
    plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.legend(('N = 10', 'N = 20', 'N = 30'))
plt.show()
```

The generated output then looks like this:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
Matplotlib:  3.2.0rc1
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

The "typical" way to plot a function is to compute 2 vectors (lists).  One of the x values and one of f(x) and then plot them.  You can either type in your x values or use one of several convenient functions such as `numpy.linspace` to make them.  You can (and should) also use list comprehension to make the y values.  Here is a toy example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def f(x):  # just return x squared
    return x**2
x = range(10)
y = [f(t) for t in x]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

produces:

[image]

If you want to make the graph smoother and use a lot of values for x, then use `numpy.linspace` perhaps like so:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,20,1000)  # low, high, number of pts
y = [np.sin(4*t) for t in x]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

You should be able to use whatever function you want to compute you y-values and use this structure.